# Sticky window bottom div on fixed div

Tags: html, css, scroll, window, sticky

i have problem with my sticky div on mobile. I would like to get a sticky window div effect in the mobile menu. So, the yellow div is supposed to cover part of the menu. I tried different solutions with position absolute and fix, unfortunately I do not want to act my way. [My website](http://mariol.hostit.pl/web/)

Sticky div:

```
<div class="tag-wrapper">
    <div class="tag">Click here to Refresh</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .tag-wrapper {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 80px;
   }

   .tag {
     position: fixed;
     background: #ffcc33;
     border: 2px solid #dfa800;
     border-top: 0px;
     padding: 3px 5px;
     bottom: 0;
   }
```

CSS my navbar:

```
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 260px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  height: 100%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100%+ 60px);
  height: calc(100%+ 60px);
  height: -moz-calc(100%);
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  color: #d8d8d8;
  background-color: #23282e;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1040;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-105%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-105%);
  transform: translateX(-105%);
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;}
```

The effect I'm trying to get is [on this page](https://www.helikon-tex.com/) after turning on the mobile look. The menu comes under sticky divs. [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em3UU.png)

Comment: Explain in detail _the sticky window div effect_ you want in that yellow div so that we can help you. Also add the part of the code you want us to check

Answer (score 0):

Here it is fixed at the bottom of the menu:

```
.tag-wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Change *white* for the color the want, it is just to know where is it

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. When I scroll through the menu at the bottom of the page, there is free space - the div does not move. Check screen https://prnt.sc/j7b1pt

Comment: I'm sorry, you will need to calculate the height once the accordion is clicked. Haven't found the way to do it... yet